# Change default button state from Cancel to OK

Tags: unity, gui, dialog

In all of the dialogs I need to click OK or change it with keyboard (right, Enter). Can this be changed for the default confirmation to be set to OK and not to Cancel?

Comment: Favour returned!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot. That's purely application-driven, not OS-driven.

#### :-(

**LQ reviewers:** that's it: no more to say, really...

Answer (score 0):

> "No, it cannot. That's purely application-driven, not OS-driven."

[Sorry that I can not comment that because I have not "50 reputation".]

[image: A dialog shown after trying to overwrite a file using Kate]

You can install Kate in Ubuntu 16.04, try to overwrite a file (you can try to save your file using the name of another existing file), and see that first it's showed the default button "No", and after that, it's showed the button "Yes".

However... it's just the opposite if you use the same Kate version under Kubuntu 16.04 (first it's showed the default button "Yes", and after that, the "No" button).

So it doesn't seem that this is application-driven?